# .htaccess RewriteRule to convert directory-type URL structure to a query

Tags: url, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

i know this question has been asked/answered several times already, but i just cant seem to get past it. so, my apologies...

while in the site dev phase, i want the browsers address bar to display: `domain.com/dev/item`

i would like the RewriteRule to change it to: `domain.com/dev/index.php?p=item`

im using the .htaccess located in the public_html directory for this. the .htaccess within public_html/dev, which works fine, is configured to redirect everybody who is not using my ip to domain.com. my apache version is 2.2.15 and i've confirmed that i am able to redirect using .htaccess, but the top level .htacess simply doesnt work. here is the code im using:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)$ dev/index.php?p=$1 [NC]
#variations tried: ^dev/(.*)+$, ^dev/(.*)+?$
```

the, including variations, results in a 404, /dev/item not found. removing the dev/ from ^dev/(.*)$ results in the correct url format, but the following server variables:

```
[REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => p=
[REDIRECT_URL] => /404.shtml
[QUERY_STRING] => p=
[REQUEST_URI] => /dev/item
```

my goal is to make a small change to support this type of rewrite for both the live site and the dev copy. but i just cant understand what im doing wrong. i really would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the / at the beginning of the rewrite paths.

Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# If request is for a file that does actually exist, don't rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 # If request is for a directory that does actually exist, don't rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^/dev/(.*)$ /dev/index.php?p=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. i tried the above code and it results in a 500 internal server error. just out of curiosity, and if this is pita to explain, dont worry about it, why would my code cause a loop?

Comment: Because the `N` in `RewriteRule ^dev/(.*)$ dev/index.php?p=$1 [NC]` means "after reaching this rule, start the rewrite process all over" and your pattern substitution will match the pattern again.

Comment: Also, can you look in your apache logs and paste the error message?

Comment: oh, i was under the impression that NC was treated as a single command, which stands for no case.. in any case, move the in-line comments to their own lines, above their rewrite conditions resolved the 500 error. but the 404 error remains.
the other thing is, im on a hosted server and there is no http.conf file and i cant find the apache error logs. im able to get my servers access logs:
[Fri Nov 12 15:07:29 2010] [error] [client my.ip..] File does not exist: /path/to/public_html/404.shtml
[Fri Nov 12 15:07:29 2010] [error] [client my.ip..] File does not exist: /path/to/public_html/dev/event

Comment: Oh, you are right about NC.  I missed that somehow.  It sounds like maybe you did not actually turn on the rewrite engine?  `RewriteEngine on` -- Also, you actually do need the leading / on the rule and replacement, so at least my answer wasn't completely stupid.  :)  You may also need to supply `RewriteBase`.  See my updated answer.

Comment: i have the rewrite engine on and im getting a 404 error with that answer. not stupid at all... hell, i cant get a basic match/replace going

Comment: Hmm, maybe use RewriteLog http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog to figure out what's going on?

Comment: based on those access logs i pasted, it appears to be ignoring or removing the /dev/

Comment: Make sure that `RewriteBase /` is in your config, and also make sure that the replacement string in the rule begins with `/`.

Comment: yea, i dont think rewritelog is supposed to be added to htaccess, i get a 500 err when its there.

Comment: still getting a 404. heres what im using:
<pre><code>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#logging can only be applied to http.conf
#RewriteLog "/dev/rewritelog.txt"
#RewriteLogLevel 9

# If request is for a file that does actually exist, don't rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If request is for a directory that does actually exist, don't rewrite.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/dev/(.*)$ /dev/index.php?p=$1 [L]
</code></pre>
bah! how do you format code here? haha

Comment: thanks for the attempt though... maybe the host might be able to provide some insight...